# How to append an element (div) that contains multiples elements inside using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an object `<div>` that contains many divs inside. And a simple button. What I want is to create the first object any time the button is clicked.

For now I can only create the object but empty, how can I do to create the div with all their child (the "hello" inside)?

Here is a simple script

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.className = 'object';
 $(".container").append(div);
});
```

```css
.object{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" type="button">
create an object
</button>
<div class="container">
<div class="object">
  <p>
  hello
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: clone it and append it?

Comment: You can append html instead of a DOM Element.

Comment: How to do this please @kernelmaster

Comment: OP, if one of these answers solved your problem, you should accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. Your container div can be thought of as a container of child div elements. So you will want to clone your object, and then append it to this container.

Check out this snippet.

```js
$(".button").click(function(){   
    $(".object:first").clone().appendTo("div.container");
});
```

```css
.object{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" type="button">
create an object
</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="object">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another possible solution is to use `html()`

```js
$(".button").on("click", function() {
    $(".container").html($(".container").html() + "<div class='object'><p>Hello</p></div>");
});
```

```css
.object{
      margin-top:10px;
      width:100px;
      height:50px;
      background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" type="button">
create an object
</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="object">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be a copy of the first item you can use `clone()`. If the element is not supposed to be in there to start, than add the element somewhere else to the page and select it.

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
 var cont = $(".container"),
        div = cont.find(".object").eq(0).clone();    
    cont.append(div);
});
```

```css
.object{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" type="button">
create an object
</button>
<div class="container">
<div class="object">
  <p>
  hello
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...clone it with true which means it copies everything including events etc... then append that clone.

If i helped please vote for my answer. :)

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
 /*var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.className = 'object';
 $(".container").append(div);*/

  //new stuff
   var clone = $(".object").clone(true);
   $(".container").append(clone);
});
```

```css
.object{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" type="button">
create an object
</button>
<div class="container">
<div class="object">
  <p>
  hello
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```